# RadTreeView make parent items expandable but not selectable

Tags: asp.net, telerik

My treeview hierarchy is like this,

```
parent 1a
    parent 2a
          child 1a
parent 1b
     child 1b
parent 1c
```

(In the hierarchy there are 700+ nodes. Child items gets loaded on demand to improve performance. )
Treeview will be initially loaded with level 1 items. I want only leaf nodes (Items with no children) to be selected. (As per the example, child 1a, child 1b, parent 1c only should be selectable)
But if an item has children, it should be expandable, but not selectable.

Tried the "Enabled" attribute, but you can't use expand as well. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

ASPX

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server" OnClientNodeClicking="OnClientNodeClicking">
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

JS

```
function OnClientNodeClicking(sender, args) {
            var node = args.get_node();
            if (node.get_parent() == node.get_treeView()) {
                args.set_cancel(true);
            }
        }
```

Edit 1 :

```
function OnClientNodeClicking(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_node().get_allNodes().length != 0) {
                args.set_cancel(true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This works, but i need to improve this a little bit. (Since Parent 2a should also be only expandable) this checks whether the parent is "tree". If I can check whether there are children then It will solve my issue.